# Finite Sum of Zeta Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $T(n) =$ the zeta function evaluated at $x = n$. Is it possible to find the sum 
Sigma ($k =1$ to $n$) of $T(k)$ ? via impropal integrals? closed form? I need this to evaluate a sum involving zeta function.

Comment: Why not call the zeta function of $\;n\;$ by $\;\zeta(n)\;$ , or even $\;z(n)\;$ ?

Comment: A suggestion: also use LaTeX, and the standard notation $\zeta(s)$. The sum equals infinity since $\zeta(1)$ is the harmonic series.