# First Sum of Zetas

Tags: summation

Can I simplify the sum: $\zeta(1) +\zeta(2) +...+\zeta(n)$ .
Whereas $\zeta$ denotes the zeta function.
I want to find the limit involving this sum but need it simplified.
Thanks.

Comment: $\zeta(1)$ is equal to complex infinity.  So perhaps you mean to start with $\zeta(2)$?

Comment: This question was already asked several times: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576266/finite-sum-of-zita-functions, and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576769/finite-sum-of-riemann-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant $\zeta(2) + \zeta(3) + \cdots + \zeta(n)$.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=2}^n \zeta(i)
&= \sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{i}} \\
&\stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{k^{i}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{(1/k)^2 - (1/k)^{n+1}}{1 - (1/k)}
\end{align*}

You need to justify the $\stackrel{?}{=}$ step.  Then take the limit as $n \to \infty$.